# query to get records based on small date from current date?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, typeorm

I have a column `loginDate` in a table. This column has value type as `Date`. As of now i am storing ISO date format value in it as `2020-07-30 18:43:09.000000`.

Now i want to write a query where logindate's `month` and `year` should be smaller. Let's say the current date `30 July 2020`  so I want to get only records of the smaller month and year. So i should not get records of `July` month. I should get smaller month and year eg. June 2020,July 2019 etc. Please tell me what should be query.

I tried this

`SELECT * FROM useres where loginDate < date_add(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 DAY)` ;

But this will get records of july as well.

Comment: You specify that the type is `date` and then you show a value with a time component.  MySQL does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
where login_date < curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day
```

This gets all the rows before the first date of the current month.

Comment: [curdate() - interval (day(curdate())-1) day](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=881beb024a5763c8ba93e441c91c55c6) I think as beginning of month.

Comment: What if date is 01-07-2020 then this logic will not work.

Comment: You did say the column type was `Date`, which contradicts our ISO date format that includes a time in the question. If you store dates as text then you've got a problem that you need to fix. A representative of a date isn't the same as a date.

Comment: What if date is 01-07-2020 then this logic will not work. 2020-07-30 18:43:09.000000

Comment: @TechChain . . . If the date is 2020-07-01, then this will choose everything before 2020-07-01.  If the date is 2020-07-31, then it will also choose everything before 2020-07-01.  That appears to be what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should break up the date into its [month](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and its [year](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year). Then create a new date with these and for day use 1. Then simply compare to the current date.

```
WHERE
STR_TO_DATE( SUBSTR(loginDate,1,10 ), '%Y-%m-%d')
<
STR_TO_DATE( 
CONCAT( 
    YEAR( CURRENT_DATE() ), '-', 
    LPAD( MONTH( CURRENT_DATE() ) ,2,'00'),
    '-01'   )
,'%Y-%m-%d' )
```

Comment: putting `loginDate ` in the middle of an expression prevents any index use.Also treating dates as strings its a bit of an ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate date expression:

So the previous month is:

```
WHERE last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month)+ interval 1 day <= login_date AND
 login_date < curdate() - interval (day(curdate())-1) day
```

The current month in the previous year is:

```
WHERE last_day(curdate() - interval 1 year - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day <= login_date AND
 login_date < curdate() - interval (day(curdate())-1) day - interval 1 year
```